# HTML, accessibilty: is it possible to label two controls with a single label?

Tags: accessibility, label, html

I have found an example in the net where the label tag and its 'for' attribute were used to hint the browser to which control the label belongs to. E.g:

```
<form>  
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" />
  <br />
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" />
</form>
```

My question is if I actually have two controls where the same single label should be assigned to the combination of both (not to each one, if possible), eg:

```
a label text + a numeric input field + a text (unit) input field
```

Should I

1. assign the label only to the numeric input field (because it can't be done) or
2. is it possible to put the numeric and text input field into a single span tag and attach the label to that span?
3. or can both input controls be placed inside the single label tag?

Which solution will work for accessibility on all browsers?

Answer (score 7):

The `for` attribute of labels can indeed be used with any element (so long as the `ID` matches) but only for a single element. Additionally, it really only makes sense for *form* elements.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1):

> for = idref [CS]
>
> This attribute explicitly associates the label being defined with another control. When present, the value of this attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of some other control in the same document. When absent, the label being defined is associated with the element's contents.

And:

> To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control element must be within the contents of the LABEL element. In this case, the LABEL **may only contain one control element**.

(emphasis mine)